# Higher Moments of a Cauchy Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, physics

all.

So, I'm working on the following problem for a statistical mechanics course.

> A physical measurement of $x$ gives results for $-\infty < x < \infty$ with probability distribution (or density) given approximately by the distribution 
>   \begin{equation}\label{prob2}
> p(x) = \frac{a}{\pi (a^2 + x^2)}
> \end{equation}
>   with $a<0$.

One part of the problem asks me to verify that the average value and the variance of $x$ are not well-defined. I'm a bit stuck at the end of the problem, and I think it is because of how I am defining what a well-defined function is. Here is my work, I will mention the part where I am stuck.

The average value of a probability distribution is given by the expectation value. Namely, 
        \begin{align}
       \label{expect1} E[x] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x p(x) dx
    \end{align}
Using the Cauchy probability function and integrating according to the equation above, we see that
        \begin{align}
        E[x] = \frac{a}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2 + a^2} dx
    \end{align}
For the expectation value to hold any meaning, it must converge. This means that $E[x]$ is 'well-behaved' and converges to a non-infinite value. So, according to the definition of convergence, 
        \begin{align}
        \lim_{t \xrightarrow{} \infty} \int_{0}^{t} x p(x) dx 
    \end{align}
must hold for our function to be well-behaved. Here I will show that the Cauchy distribution is not well-defined at its first moment, which subsequently means that its variance ($\text{Var}(x) = E[x^2] - E[x]^2$) also is not not well-defined.

Taking the integral, 
        \begin{align}
        \int_0^t \frac{x}{x^2 + a^2}dx &= \frac{1}{a^2} \int_0^t \frac{x}{\frac{x^2}{a^2} + 1} dx
    \end{align}
    Making a change of variables such that $u = \frac{x^2}{a^2} \Rightarrow{} \frac{2}{a^2}du = xdx$ gives
        \begin{align}
        \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{t^2 / a^2} \frac{1}{u + 1} du &= \frac{1}{2} \ln{(u+1)}_{\big |_0^{t^2 /a^2}} \\ 
        &= \frac{1}{2}\ln{\bigg (\frac{t^2}{a^2} + 1 \bigg )}
    \end{align}
    Taking the limit as $t \rightarrow \infty$,
        \begin{align}
        \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2}\ln{\bigg (\frac{t^2}{a^2} + 1 \bigg )} = \infty
    \end{align}
    In a similar fashion, we can see that for $-\infty < t < 0$, 
        \begin{align}
        \int_t^0 \frac{x}{x^2 + a^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2}\ln{\bigg (\frac{t^2}{a^2} + 1 \bigg )}
    \end{align}
   Which, for the limit as $t \rightarrow -\infty$, 
        \begin{align}
        \lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} -\frac{1}{2}\ln{\bigg (\frac{t^2}{a^2} + 1 \bigg )} = -\infty
    \end{align}

This is where I am stuck. I do not see how the limits of this function as $t \rightarrow 0$ from either side is not well-defined, as the limits seem to show that the value at $x=0$ is zero. I read that a function that is not well-defined is not one-to-one, but I do not see how this is the case here.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: All you have to show is that $E|X|$ diverges (the integral is not absolutely convergent) for $E(X)$ to not exist. Same goes for $E(X^2)$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, So the problem is finished baring an explanation at the end?

Comment: I mean show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x|p(x)\,dx$ diverges, instead of working with  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xp(x)\,dx$. Since this is the definition of existence of moments.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, do you have some source that I could read regarding this? I'd like to get some background on the topic.

Comment: Google search for moments of Cauchy distribution. In general $E(g(X))$ is said to exist if $E(|g(X)|)$ exists (that is, finite) for any function $g$ of $X$. Any standard probability or statistics book would mention this while defining moments of a random variable or distribution.

Comment: Your work suggests the mean would be $E[X]=\infty-\infty$, which is certainly not well defined;  something similar happens for all odd moments about $0$.  You cannot find central moments about the mean (such as the variance) since the mean is not well defined.  You could find $E[X^2]=\infty+\infty$ which is arguably well defined though infinite; something similar happens for all even moments about $0$.

Comment: To start, maybe look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution). You need to set their parameters $\gamma = 1$ and $x_0 = 0.$